# Add multiple projects to Github repository

Tags: c#, github, github-for-windows

I have a C# solution. The solution contains the main project and about 15 or so projects in different folders. I add a reference to these projects inside the main project.

Is there a way to add all the projects inside the solution into a Github repository?

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices: 
1) Add all your source code as single folder in one single github repository. 
2) Add all your projects into their own separate github repository.

Option 2 is preferred over option 1 as it allows different teams to work on individual projects without worrying about other projects. Big monolithic repositories soon end up as spaghetti code as some day a programmer in hurry would add code in one project and use it in other project and break Separation of Concern.

Option 2 does add maintenance overhead but that is minimal user rights. Benefits are faster checkout for smaller projects and lesser merge conflicts.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think I'll go with option 2. If have to pull all my projects every time I have to work on it, is there a way to automate this process in Git Bash. I'm used to working in Windows, so a batch file??? Maybe???